# gmake using sh.exe causes build errors

Tags: windows, bash, shell, gnu-make

I have a makefile that works on a Windows system when sh.exe is not on path. But when sh.exe is on Windows path, it stops with an error. Apparently, sh.exe can not handle paths with mixed / and \ such as this one:

```
 cc $CFLAGS) C:\a\b/c/d/myfile.c
```

it generates the following error

```
 Fatal error: could not open source file "c:ab/c/d/myfile.c"
```

As I am not able to change the makefile (it is auto generated by some application), how can I force gmake not to use sh.exe or force sh.exe to accept such files?

Comment: Can you modify your path so that `cmd` is found before `sh`? Is this a cygwin environment?

Comment: @AdamBurry: No I can not change the path as I am developing a system that should work on customer system and I can not change the path on customer system. No I am developing using TI environment.

Comment: what about `gmake SHELL="cmd"`? http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Choosing-the-Shell.html#Choosing-the-Shell

Comment: @AdamBurry: I tried to set SHELL environment variable without any success. I even put SHELL="cmd" on make file to test without any success.

Comment: @AdamBurry: Thanks it worked. Please add your comment as answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `gmake SHELL="cmd"`. See the [GNU make docs](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Choosing-the-Shell.html#Choosing-the-Shell) for more information. In particular, note this tidbit:

> Note that this extended search for the shell is limited to the cases
>   where SHELL is set from the Makefile; if it is set in the environment
>   or command line, you are expected to set it to the full pathname of
>   the shell, exactly as things are on Unix.

Comment: In the same document it also says "Unlike most variables, the variable SHELL is never set from the environment. This is because the SHELL environment variable is used to specify your personal choice of shell program for interactive use. It would be very bad for personal choices like this to affect the functioning of makefiles. See Variables from the Environment."

WTF??

Comment: @antred The question was about gmake on a Windows system. gmake treats the SHELL variable differently in that case. Specifically, "However, on MS-DOS and MS-Windows the value of SHELL in the environment is used, since on those systems most users do not set this variable, and therefore it is most likely set specifically to be used by make."

Comment: Oh, I wasn't complaining about your answer. I'm just puzzled at the GNU Make documentation regarding this issue, which in my opinion just flat-out contradicts itself.